# Avoiding Division By 0 Error

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have been trying to make a calculation in SQL but the problem I have is that sometimes there is a chance that one of the numbers could be 0, which of course would cause a SQL Server error.  I tried to modify my case statement from null to 0, but in doing such caused false data to be returned for other items.  What should I do in this scenario to have the calculation return accurately, and if it would return a division by 0 error, return 0?

```
Select product,
count(distinct case when numavaliable is null then ID else null end),
count(distinct product),
count(distinct case when numavaliable is null then ID else null end)/count(distinct      product)
From ProductionInfo
Group By product
```

Comment: If you are grouping by `product` and counting distinct `product` per group, that will always be 1, unless `product` is null. The question is, why would you want to divide by that value?

Comment: I have to have the Group By statement or else it errors out.  I agree with your statement that it will always be 1 as that is another issue I am facing.

Comment: Perhaps you don't need `distinct` for that particular `count`.

Comment: One more "just-in-case" note for you: you are dividing an integer by an integer, in which case SQL Server will perform *integral* division: the result will be an integer too.

Comment: Even if I modify it to be Select Distinct(Product) - I am still required to use a Group By statement.  -- And thank you for the note about the division, I was aware of that, and that is what I was after :)

Comment: If you're grouping by product, you don't need DISTINCT(Product). DISTINCT doesn't work on individual columns anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `NULLIF` and `ISNULL` functions.

```
Select product,
count(distinct case when numavaliable is null then ID else null end),
count(distinct product),
ISNULL (count(distinct case when numavaliable is null then ID else null end)/NULLIF(count(distinct      product), 0), 0)
From ProductionInfo
Group By product
```

Comment: Perfect solution, thank you!  I will mark as answer when my timer (I believe there is 8 min left) expires.  Thank you again!

Answer (score -2):

You could use IF on the column to check if it is 0.

```
SELECT IF(y = 0, 'NaN', x/y) FROM YOURTABLE;
```

Comment: SQL Server 2012 has `IIF` (not `IF`) but it would need to be `NULL` not `'NaN'` as that would fail casting to numeric.